# Translation of a phrase for CV

Tags: translation

How would you translate this to Japanese:

> Network security, cyber security and information security expert and adviser.

Is this correct:

> ネットワーク・セキュリティ、サイバー・セキュリティと情報・セキュリティの専門と顧問。

Is it best if I dropped the last two "security"s?

Like this:

> Network, cyber and information security expert and adviser.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the ending with 専門と顧問. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: TBH, It looks machine-translated, but maybe that is just me.

Comment: It is machine-translated. What is your suggestion?

Comment: We should probably clarify that using Google Translate doesn't count as making your own attempt at translating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can drop the *first* two セキュリティ's, like in English.
- 顧問 is not bad, but it sounds a bit too grandiose to me, because it's mainly used for lawyers, economists, politicians and such. And in reality, 顧問 is often used like an honorary title after someone is effectively retired. I hear アドバイザー or コンサルタント more often for actively-working security consultants.
- 専門 is "specialty" and does not directly refer to a person. What you may need instead is 専門家【せんもんか】 or エキスパート, which means "specialist/expert". However, I doubt we need this word in the first place, because アドバイザー already implies it. (And 専門家**と**顧問 sounds like there are two people—an expert and an adviser)

So if I'm allowed to modify it so that it looks natural and short, I would say:

> ネットワーク・サイバー・情報セキュリティアドバイザー